# How to fix layout of iPhone6 in Xcode7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, iphone-6

I can't fix the layout of iPhone6 in Xcode7.
I tried them

・choose them at App Icons and Launch Images in General(in target).
App Icons Source→AppIcon
Launch Images Source→LaunchImage
Launch Screen File→(blank)
→the black bar appeared upside and downside in all devices.

・choose them at App Icons and Launch Images in General(in target) and make LaunchScreen.storyboard

App Icons Source→AppIcon

Launch Images Source→LaunchImage

Launch Screen File→LaunchScreen.storyboard

→I couldn't build the project because of the error "WatchOS storyboards do not support target device type 'iPhone' "

・choose them at App Icons and Launch Images in General(in target).

App Icons Source→AppIcon

Launch Images Source→LaunchImage

Launch Screen File→Launch Image

[when it is 5s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzoGd.png)

[when it is 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p324o.png)

→the black bar didn't appear and fixed the layouts in the devices before iPhone5s.
but in iPhones after iPhone6, the layout were broken.

How can I fix the layout in the devices after iPhone6?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a LaunchImage for iPhone 6 and later devices.

Comment: I set a LaunchImage for Retina HD 5.5,Retina HD4.7,Retina HD5.5.but these don't work.